# .nextToken() encountere a space it throws an java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I have a csv file that contain one line;

'2013-05-25 23:59:59','-126125372','299134596','-1272989684','1826558680','-441013765','-441013765'

Every time the token encounter a space (e.g. "2013-05-25 23:59:59") it throws a error. Im using a StringTokenizer

Any idea how this happen?

Btw here's my code;

```
        Scanner x = new Scanner(new FileReader("c:\\test.csv"));
        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(x.next());           

        while (token.hasMoreElements())
        {
            System.out.println(token.nextElement()); 

        }
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a CSV parser? And why would you use `StringTokenizer` instead of `String#split()`? _["`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the java.util.regex package instead."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)_

Comment: Are you sure `x.next()` is returning what you think? Also I'd look into using possibly a `String.split()` method instead.

Comment: This probably has to do with the double quotes you have in your first token.

Comment: Franklin, yes it works. I never encountered a error with the element without spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your CSV contains the line:

'2013-05-25 23:59:59','-126125372','299134596','-1272989684','1826558680','-441013765','-441013765'

The code you just posted

```
    Scanner x = new Scanner(new FileReader("c:\\test.csv"));
    StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(x.next());
```

will only capture `'2013-05-25` as a String with `x.next()`, see the javadoc for [`Scanner#next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/). From the javadoc,

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern,
>   which by default matches whitespace.

So `next()` will return everything up to the next space as a String. Use `nextLine()` instead, to return the full line.

```
StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(x.nextLine());
```

Comment: @gibson You're welcome. The javadoc is extremely powerful for java classes. Use it to your advantage.

Answer (score 0):

I assume x is an Iterator. whose [next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next%28%29) method throws that exception.
If you insist on using StringTokenizer legacy class, then check that there actually are more elements using [x.hasNext()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#hasNext%28%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
String str = "2013-05-25 23:59:59,'-126125372','299134596','-1272989684','1826558680','-441013765','-441013765'";
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str);

        System.out.println("---- Split by space ------");
        while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
            System.out.println(st.nextElement());
        }
```

you have invalid character(") 2013-05-25 23:59:59",' after 59.change it or skip it

Comment: you could thinking about escaping the quotes with `\"`

Comment: @Franklin I don't know whether that charachter is needed to him or it is a mistake.so it is up to him to decide whether escape it or miss it.

Comment: @Sanjaya, this one will not throw an error but it capture only the "2013-05-25

Comment: @gibson you only have one space here and that is after 2013-05-25 .so it will give you two tokens one is 2013-05-25 and the other is 23:59:59,'-126125372','299134596','-1272989684','1826558680','-441013765','-441013765' .as I have add a println these two will be printed in two lines